# c++ segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

This is a TSP problem I am trying to compile it.

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this segmentation fault.

The error doesnt give me a line number..
I'm just trying to get this to run thoroughly, any help would be appreciated!

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include<cstdio>
#define N 1000

using namespace std;

//Travelling sales man problem , travelling between 100 cities.
//initializing the path lengths between cities and the paths to be included
//in population



void initialize(int pathlen[][100],int path[][100])
{
    int i,j,k;


    //obtaining pathlengths
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
            if(j<i)           //path length from a to b will be same as b to a
            {
                pathlen[i][j]=pathlen[j][i];
            }

            if(j==i)         // path length from a to a will be 0
            {
                pathlen[i][j]=0;

            }

            if(j>i)         // rest initialized
            {
                do{
                pathlen[i][j]= random();
                }while(!pathlen[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }

    // display the path lengths

    printf("\n\tThe PATH LENGTHS ARE: \n" );

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
            printf(" %5d ",pathlen[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }


    // generating the population

    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
            path[i][j]=random();

            for(k=j-1;k>=0;k--)
            {
                if(path[i][j]==path[i][k])  //checking to avoid repeatition
                {
                    path[i][j] = random();
                    k=j;
                }
            }
        }
    }



}

// evaluating the fitness function or total distance

void evaluate(int pathlen[100][100],int path[50][100],int fx[50])
{
    int sum =0,i,j,a,b;

    //obtaing the sum of the path taken
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            a=path[i][j];
            b=path[i][j+1];
            sum=sum+pathlen[a][b];
        }
        fx[i]=sum;

    }

    //display the paths generated
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n\tPATH \t\tf(x) \n\n");
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        printf("\t");
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
            printf(" %d",path[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\t%d",fx[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

}

//selecting the two points for cross over and then performing partial Crossover

void selection(int fx[50],int pos[2],int posmax[2])
{
    int min1=fx[0],min2=fx[0],i,max1=fx[0],max2=fx[0];
    pos[0]=0;
    pos[1]=0;
    posmax[0]=0;
    posmax[1]=0;

    //calculating the minimum postion
    for(i=1;i<50;i++)
    {
        if(fx[i]<min1)
        {
            min1=fx[i];
            pos[0]=i;

        }
    }
    //calaculating the second minimum position

    for(i=1;i<50;i++)
    {
        if(fx[i]<min2&&i!=pos[0])
        {
            min2=fx[i];
            pos[1]=i;

        }
    }

    //calculating the max position

    for(i=1;i<50;i++)
    {
        if(fx[i]>max1)
        {
            max1=fx[i];
            posmax[0]=i;

        }
    }
    //calculating the second max position

    for(i=1;i<50;i++)
    {
        if(fx[i]>max2&&i!=posmax[0])
        {
            max2=fx[i];
            posmax[1]=i;

        }

    }
    printf("\n\tFIRST MINIMUM=%4d \tPOSITION=%4d\n\tSECOND MINIMUN=%4d \tPOSITION=%4d\n\tFIRST MAXIMUM=%4d \tPOSITION=%4d\n\tSECOND MAXIMUM=%4d \tPOSITION=%4d\n",min1,pos[0],min2,pos[1],max1,posmax[0],max2,posmax[1]);

}

//PERFORMING PARTIAL CROSSOVER

void crossover(int pos[2],int path[][100],int child[2][100])
{
    int crosspt1,crosspt2,j,i,temp,temp1[2][100],temp2;
    //TAKING 2 CROSS POINTS
    do
    {
        crosspt1=random();
    }while(crosspt1>2) ;
    do
    {
        crosspt2=random();
    }while(crosspt2<=3);
    //clrscr();
    printf("\n\n\t The CROSSOVER POINTS ARE : %d , %d ",crosspt1,crosspt2);
    printf("\n\n\tTHE PATHS FOR CROSSOVER ARE");
    printf("\n\n\t\t");

    for(j=0;j<100;j++)
    {
        child[0][j]=path[pos[0]][j];
        printf(" %d",child[0][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\t\t");
    for(j=0;j<100;j++)
    {
        child[1][j]=path[pos[1]][j];
        printf(" %d",child[1][j]);
    }

    int cnt=0;
    //swapping the paths between two crosspoints

    for(j=crosspt1+1;j<=crosspt2;j++)
    {
        temp1[1][cnt]=child[0][j];
        temp1[0][cnt]=child[1][j];
        temp=child[0][j];
        child[0][j]=child[1][j];
        child[1][j]=temp;
        cnt++;

    }
    //performing partial crossover

    int k,m;
    for(m=0;m<2;m++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<crosspt1+1;i++)   //taking the path before crosspoint
        {
            for(j=0;j<cnt;j++)   //comparing the path within crossover point
            {
                if(child[m][i]==temp1[m][j]) //if found then
                {
                    if(m==0)   //for child 1
                    {
                        temp2=temp1[1][j];   //take the path from child2 crossover

                        for(k=0;k<100;k++)
                        {
                            if(child[m][k]==temp2) //if still the path repeats then repeat the process again
                            { temp2=child[1][k];
                              k=0;
                            }
                        }

                        child[m][i]=temp2;   //finally putting the value in child

                    }
                    else  //for child 2
                    {
                        temp2=temp1[0][j];
                        for(k=0;k<100;k++)
                        {
                            if(child[m][k]==temp2)
                            {temp2=child[0][k];
                             k=0;

                            }
                        }
                        child[m][i]=temp2;
                    }


                }


            }
        }
    }

    for(m=0;m<2;m++)
    {
        for(i=crosspt2+1;i<100;i++)   //now chehcking the path after the second cross point
        {
            for(j=0;j<cnt;j++)   //comparing the path within crossover point
            {
                if(child[m][i]==temp1[m][j])  //if found then
                {
                    if(m==0)   //for child 1
                    {
                        temp2=temp1[1][j];   //take the path from child2 crossove
                        for(k=0;k<100;k++)
                        {
                            if(child[m][k]==temp2) //if still the path repeats then repeat the process again
                            {temp2=child[1][k];
                             k=0;
                             }
                        }
                        child[m][i]=temp2;  //finally assigning the value
                    }
                    else   //for child 2
                    {

                        temp2=temp1[0][j];
                        for(k=0;k<cnt;k++)
                        {
                            if(child[m][k]==temp2)
                            {temp2=child[0][k];
                             k=0;
                             }
                        }
                        child[m][i]=temp2;
                    }

                }


            }
        }
    }
    //display AfTER  CROSSOVER
    printf("\n\tAFTER CROSSOVER\n\t\t");

    for(j=0;j<100;j++)
    {
        printf(" %d",child[0][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\t\t");
    for(j=0;j<100;j++)
    {
        printf(" %d",child[1][j]);
    }


}

//insering the paths in population removing those having maximum populaiton

void insert(int child[2][100],int posmax[2],int path[50][100])
{
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
    {
        path[posmax[0]][j]=child[0][j];
        path[posmax[1]][j]=child[1][j];
    }


}

// performing mutation

void mutation(int child[2][100])
{
    int sel=random();
    int pos1=random();
    int pos2=random();
    int temp=child[sel][pos1];
    child[sel][pos1]=child[sel][pos2];
    child[sel][pos2]=temp;
}

void main()
{
    //clrscr();
    //randomize();


    int pathlen[100][100],path[50][100],fx[50],pos[2],posmax[2],child[2][100];


    printf("\n\t\t\t TRAVELLING SALESMAN PROBLEM ");
    printf("\n\t\t\t_____________________________");
    printf("\n\n\n\t\tTHE TRAVELLING SALES MAN PROBLEM DEALS WITH THE FACT");
    printf("\n\n\t\tTHAT A SALESMAN TRAVELS BETWEEN CITIES TAKING THE PATH");
    printf("\n\n\t\tTHAT IS OF MINIMUN DISTANCE.");

    //getch();
    //clrscr();
    initialize(pathlen,path);
    evaluate(pathlen,path,fx);
    //getch();
    selection(fx,pos,posmax);
    crossover(pos,path,child);
    mutation(child);
    //getch();
    insert(child,posmax,path);

    for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
    {
        evaluate(pathlen,path,fx);
        selection(fx,pos,posmax);
        crossover(pos,path,child);
        mutation(child);
        insert(child,posmax,path);

    }
    evaluate(pathlen,path,fx);
    selection(fx,pos,posmax);
    crossover(pos,path,child);
    insert(child,posmax,path);

    evaluate(pathlen,path,fx);
    //getch();


}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger? It will run into a segmentation fault and should specify where it's happening, and you can get the stacktrace at the time it happened.

Comment: No I'm using putty to compile..the reason being I have to parallelize it and I just cant figure out how to fix the segmentation fault

Comment: putty is just a terminal emulator, you're using `g++`. You can compile the program with debug symbols with the `-g` flag, and you might want to compile with zero optimization just in case with `-O0`. Then you can load the program with `gdb` and follow a tutorial like this:  http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Comment: **Please** do not simply post all of your code and expect other people to fix it for you. This is both an ineffective way to learn, and also frustrating for those who want to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

run it in gdb and then when the segfault occurs, run type **bt** to get the line number. Just make sure you compile your code with **-g** flag.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from running it in gdb ....

1. If running under Linux

   1. Let it crash and create a core dump. Now you can study the core dump with gdb and see where the problem happened.
   2. Run it through valgrind with --tool=memcheck. For any memory related issues which can result in segmentation fault, the report it generates will help you to resolve it.
2. If you are running under Windows XP

   1. Use your Dr. Watson to capture a Dump.  Then Use WinDBG to debug the generated dump.
   2. If you are running with Win 2003 or beyond, you have to write code to generate [dump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
   3. If you have the luxury to use Visual Studio, you can use it to debug and let it crash. It will most possible take you to the problem code, but remember not always this works.
   4. You can install WinDBG as a JIT or even Visual Studio and use it to capture the crash state,